# Display caret on a blurred input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I would like to display the caret (the blinking typing cursor) that appears in focused inputs and textareas, but I'd like this to happen when said elements are *not* focused. The purpose is to do a live preview / give the user visual hints about what to do. Could this be done?

I just found [this](http://protosketch.io/) example (the animated tagline under the video).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var focused = $('input');
var hovered = $('.not-focused');

hovered.onmouseout(function()
{
  focused.focus();
}
});
```

When cursor goes out from some element with class "not-focused", the input become focused. If it not exactly you needs, tell me more. Is blinking cursor should be inside the input field or it should be like running string or some kind of animation?